# Populate dropdown with JSON and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, drop-down-menu

I am trying to populate a dropdown menu from another dropdown.

This happened with the `onChange` event of first dropdown but I have problem when I select one of the options from dropdown 1 then it do `getJson` and it returns correct values in JSON, but the problem is that dropdown is populated every time even if I select the same value.

Here is the code:

```
$.getJSON("ajax.php", 
    { m: "modules/json/json-get-category",
      r: $('#id_project').has('option').val()
    }, 
    function(data){
        var html = '';
        var len = data.length;
        alert(len);
        //$('#id_category').val('').trigger('chosen:updated');
        for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
            html += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].catName + '</option>';
        }
        $('#id_category').append(html);
});
```

Returned JSON:

```
[
    {"id":"27","catName":"Hardware support"},
    {"id":"29","catName":"test"}
]
```

The dropdown1 has correct value on first onChange event, but after it starts to duplicate values:

Example: I have 2 Hardware support, 2 test ... and it just goes to add on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove all options before adding the new options. Before your for loop, add the following:

```
$("#id_category").find("option").remove();
```

This should remove the current items and make room for the new ones.

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of your function, remove the existing options

```
$('#id_category').empty();
```